# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm making a REST API to register a user using `PHP` and `Slim` framework.
It's giving me an error when I run it in advanced REST client:

`{"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null}}`

The code for the register module is as follows:

```
function insertUpdate() {
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $update = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name,email,password,phoneNumber,imageUrl,created_at) VALUES (:name, :email, :password, :phoneNumber, :imageUrl, :created_at)";
    try {
        $db = getDB();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
        $stmt->bindParam("name", $update->name);
        $stmt->bindParam("email", $update->email);
        $stmt->bindParam("password",$update->password);
        $stmt->bindParam("phoneNumber",$update->phoneNumber);
        $stmt->bindParam("imageUrl",$update->imageUrl);
        $time=time();
        $stmt->bindParam("created_at", $time);

        $stmt->execute();
        echo "Register successfull";
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        //error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, '/var/tmp/php.log');
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/v1/index.php(71): Slim\Slim::handleErrors(8, 'Trying to get p...', '/Applications/X...', 71, Array)
#1 [internal function]: insertUpdate()
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/v1/Slim/Route.php(462): call_user_func_array('insertUpdate', Array)
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/v1/Slim/Slim.php(1326): Slim\Route->dispatch()
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/v1/Slim/Middleware/Flash.php(85): Slim\Slim->call()
#5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/v1/Slim/Middleware/MethodOverride.php(92): Slim\Middleware\Flash->call()
#6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/v1/Slim/Middleware/PrettyExceptions.php(67): Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride->call()
#7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/v1/Slim/Slim.php(1271): Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call()
#8 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/v1/index.php(14): Slim\Slim->run()
#9 {main}
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: `$update->name` is empty or blank.  try to echo it if it really has a value.

Comment: @roullie I am trying to print $update->name but its giving me internal server error

Comment: Check your logs to see which line the error lies at and the stack trace.

Comment: @D4V1D I have updated the question with stack trace and error is in the line where i am bindParam with $update->name

Comment: Do `var_dump($upate);` then. It seems that `$update` is not an object.

Comment: @D4V1D After adding this it is giving 404 Page not found error

Comment: This is irrelevant. Are you sure you've added this line right after assigning `$update` the return value of the function `json_decode()`?

Comment: @D4V1D okay its working i have written the url wrong. thank you for your help

Comment: @D4V1D its giving the same error sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: @Corrupt: If it's working, what's the output of `var_dump($update);` then?

Comment: @D4V1D Its giving null and then its saying same error : Internal Server Error

Comment: As per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php): "*NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit*". You will need to dig into what `$request->getBody()` stores.

Comment: @D4V1D I am printing the $request->getBody() and its giving the value but when i add a general exception catch block its giving error: {"error":{"text":Invalid data received}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function insertUpdate() {
        $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
        parse_str($request->getBody(),$update); 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name,email,password,phoneNumber,imageUrl,created_at) VALUES (:name, :email, :password, :phoneNumber, :imageUrl, :created_at)";
        try {
            //Validate your filed before insert in db
            if(!is_array($update) || (!$update)) {
                throw new Exception('Invalid data received');   
            }
            // put your require filed list here
            if((!$update['name']) || (!$update['email']) || (!$update['password'])){
                throw new Exception('Missing values for require fields');
            }
            $db = getDB();
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
            $stmt->bindParam("name", $update['name']);
            $stmt->bindParam("email", $update['email']);
            $stmt->bindParam("password",$update['password']);
            $stmt->bindParam("phoneNumber",$update['phoneNumber']);
            $stmt->bindParam("imageUrl",$update['imageUrl']);
            $time=time();
            $stmt->bindParam("created_at", $time);

            $stmt->execute();
            echo "Register successfull";
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            //error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, '/var/tmp/php.log');
            echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
        }catch(Exception $e) {
            //error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, '/var/tmp/php.log');
            echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
        }
    }
```

Updated code as per request recieved

Comment: check your $request->getBody() and how your are calling API ?

Comment: Its giving me the same error and i am using advanced rest client to check the api

Comment: comment out var_dump($update); die; and check again i have updated code to catch general exception

Comment: Its giving the error: {"error":{"text":Invalid data received}} and after request when I am echoing the $request->getBody(); its giving the data that i have entered

Comment: @Corrupt your $update is not object and you are trying to get property from that is the issue

Comment: How to resolve this error and data is printing like this:

name=pulkit&email=adfkjn&password=dmsd&phoneNumber=kdf&imageUrl=asdnf&created_at=akfn

Comment: @Corrupt try this parse_str($request->getBody(),$data); var_dump($data)

Comment: I change it and its giving me output like name=pulkit&email=adfkjn&password=dmsd&phoneNumber=kdf&imageUrl=asdnf&created_at=akfnarray(6) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(6) "pulkit"
  ["email"]=>
  string(6) "adfkjn"
  ["password"]=>
  string(4) "dmsd"
  ["phoneNumber"]=>
  string(3) "kdf"
  ["imageUrl"]=>
  string(5) "asdnf"
  ["created_at"]=>
  string(4) "akfn"
}
{"error":{"text":Trying to get property of non-object}}