# Integrity constraint violation SLIM Restful MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, rest, slim

Heyho,

i ran into problems with my SLIM Restful-API. I looked up other similar problems with answers, [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900755/integrity-constraint-violation-1048-column-name-cannot-be-null) is extremely close to mine but i had no luck to get it to work. The main point is that my API was working fine before and i didn't even change a thing since then. Deleting is working fine, while UPDATE and ADD doesn't work.

I use two things to test it, the first thing is CURL:

**ADD:**

function:

```
function addTech() {
$request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
$tech = json_decode($request->getBody());
$sql = "INSERT INTO tech (tech_lastname, tech_firstname, tech_adress, tech_zip, tech_tel, user_id) VALUES (:tech_lastname, :tech_firstname, :tech_adress, :tech_zip, :tech_tel, :user_id)";
try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("tech_lastname", $tech->tech_lastname);
    $stmt->bindParam("tech_firstname", $tech->tech_firstname);
    $stmt->bindParam("tech_adress", $tech->tech_adress);
    $stmt->bindParam("tech_zip", $tech->tech_zip);
    $stmt->bindParam("tech_tel", $tech->tech_tel); 
    $stmt->bindParam("user_id", $tech->user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $tech->tech_id = $db->lastInsertId();
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($tech);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() . '}}';
}

}
```

Curl:

```
c:\curl>curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"tech_lastname":"why","tech_firstname":"why","tech_adress":"why","tech_zip":"why","tech_tel":"why","user_id":"1"}' http://localhost/itec-api/tech
```

Error:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 17 May 2016 10:57:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.11
Content-Length: 106
Content-Type: text/html

{"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null}}
```

**UPDATE:**

function:

```
function updateTech($tech_id) {
$request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
$body = $request->getBody();
$tech = json_decode($body);
$sql = "UPDATE tech SET user_id=:user_id, tech_lastname=:tech_lastname, tech_firstname=:tech_firstname, tech_adress=:tech_adress, tech_zip=:tech_zip, tech_tel=:tech_tel WHERE tech_id=:tech_id";
try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("user_id", $tech->user_id);
    $stmt->bindParam("tech_lastname", $tech->tech_lastname);
    $stmt->bindParam("tech_firstname", $tech->tech_firstname);
    $stmt->bindParam("tech_adress", $tech->tech_adress);
    $stmt->bindParam("tech_zip", $tech->tech_zip);
    $stmt->bindParam("tech_tel", $tech->tech_tel);
    $stmt->bindParam("tech_id", $tech_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($tech);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}
}
```

Curl:

```
curl -i -X PUT -d '{"tech_id":"3","tech_firstname":"updatetest"}' http://localhost/itec-api/tech/3
```

Error:

```
{"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`itec_app_workflow`.`tech`, CONSTRAINT `fk_techniker_user1` FOR
EIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)}}
```

---

---

I guess the problem comes from the getBody. I tried an echo

```
echo '$request:' . $request->getBody() . '</br>';
```

Got this:

```
$request:'{tech_lastname:why,tech_firstname:why,tech_adress:why,tech_zip:why,tech_tel:why,user_id:1}'</br>{"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot


be null}}
```

And here, the Tables:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `itec_app_workflow`.`user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `itec_app_workflow`.`user` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `user_email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `user_role` INT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(150) NULL,
  `salt` VARCHAR(150) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `itec_app_workflow`.`tech`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `itec_app_workflow`.`tech` (
  `tech_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tech_lastname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `tech_firstname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `tech_adress` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `tech_zip` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `tech_tel` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tech_id`, `user_id`),
  INDEX `fk_techniker_user1_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_techniker_user1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `itec_app_workflow`.`user` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I really hope you guys can help me. 
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I tried that, but it doesnt change the outcome

Comment: @YvesLeBorg yes, there are two entries in the `user` table

Comment: @YvesLeBorg `user_id:1` and `user_id:2` are in the table `user`.  Three Techinicans are using `user_id:1` and noone is using `user_id:2` currently.

If i try to add a Technician with `user_id:2`the same error appears.

Comment: yep ... this all works on mysql cli.  The only way to replicate is if I force "user_id" to a value of null in the insert statement. Somehow, the user_id is not travelling properly all the way to your `$tech` variable. Luck tracking that!